# how to check if a record exists in sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

[image]

My Question is: How to check if record exist or not ?

Description is: I have two fragments

1- Main Fragment==> which contains recyclerview, in this recyclerview data comes from firestore, and save this data into sqlite database when user click on recyclerview single item.

2- Orders Fragment==> which contains recyclerview, in this recyclerview data comes from sqlite which is saved from main fragment.

My questions about when i return on main fragment on pressing back stack,
i want to check that data is stored in sqlite already or not, if exist then get product quantity and replace it in main fragment on single item in recyclerview(product quantity textview is disabled, if record found endabled it and replace value which is comes from sqlite if record exist ) .

Comment: are you storing order data in sqlite? provide some code then i can help you

Comment: yes, i'm storing my data into sqlite, what type of code you required?

Comment: How about a simple select request on your data ? If it returns something, then the data exists, else it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your problem but I think you are trying to check if any data inserted into SQLite database.

In order to do that, I assume you already defined your functions in your `DatabaseHelper.class` to do standard processes because you are only asking how to check if there is any data or not. You need a function in your helper class to check if there is any data and call it from your `MainFragment.java` class.

### You didn't give any code snippet so I'm just going to assume their declarations.

Let's say you have an activity with `MainFragment.java` and `layout_mainfragment.xml`

In your `DatabaseHelper.class`:

```
public String checkRecord(String productName){
        this.db = getWritableDatabase();
        //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1,productName);
        String table = "record_table";
        String[] columns = {"product_name","product_quantity"};
        String selection = "product_name =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {productName};
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String orderBy = null;
        String limit = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("product_quantity"));
    }
```

This should return product quantity of any product name that function parameter is **IF** it finds any index.

In your `layout_mainfragment.xml`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment_recordCount"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Then in your `MainFragment.java` class:

```
TextView recordCount;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker_specification);
        recordCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainFragment_recordCount);
        DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
        String productRecord = helper.checkRecord("productname");
        //checkRecord will return quantity if index found and give productRecord that value.
        if(!productRecord.equals("")){
                recordCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recordCount.setText(productRecord);
                // If not empty, make TextView visible and set it's text to that quantity.
        }

         ....

        //(Your onCreate goes on)
         ....


}
```

Comment: I'm trying to check , is required already saved or not , if yes, then get total quantity of product from sqlite and replace record in main fragment

Comment: Check edited answer. `checkRecord` function should return the quantity if there is an index found and put that value to `productRecord`.

Answer (score 0):

on Main Fragment

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser)
        {
          //check sqlite item with firestore list item and update list and then notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```